# Where is Internet Explorer located on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

On a computer running Windows 7, I deleted the shortcut to Internet Explorer.

In which directory is Internet Explorer installed?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Press the start button, and start typing "Internet Explorer". It should pop up at the top of the list.

From there, you can drag and drop it as a shortcut to your desktop or wherever you want to put it.

Comment: To expand on Chris Dwyer's post: Press the start button, and start typing "Internet Explorer". It should pop up at the top of the list. You can now right-click on it, and select "Pin to Taskbar" or "Pin to Start Menu".

Answer (score 37):

On 64-bit:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe`

On 32-bit:

`C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe`

Comment: Isn't it the other way around?

Comment: No. There is no \Program Files(x86) folder on a 32-bit Windows.

Comment: Ahh i see what you are saying now(thats for the 32 bit .exe on that bit type). I read it as the 64 bit version is in x86 and the 32 bit version is not.

Comment: I updated my Windows 7 yesterday, and IE11 was included. But there's no iexplore.exe anymore, any idea why it vanished? (The folders still exist with several DLLs etc., seems like just the main executable is gone). A manual installation fails, 'cause there is "a newer version installed" -.-

Comment: Wrong! On a 32-bit Windows, 32-bit programs go under `%ProgramFiles%`. On a 64-bit Windows, 64-bit programs go under `%ProgramFiles%` and 32-bit programs go under `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`. [more info](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/32-64-bit-windows-folder-x86-syswow64.htm)

Comment: @orad I think you didn't read my answer correctly. I listed the location that 32-bit Internet Explorer is located for each architecture, since the OP didn't specify whether he was on x86 or x64. You may want to read an answer more than once before you lead with a `Wrong!` :)

Comment: Please read the question again. It is not asking for 32-bit only version on each architecture. And your answer is not explaining what you have in mind.

Comment: @orad I don't care to argue with you about an almost 5 year old answer, but apply some common sense. The default Internet Explorer is not 64-bit. Most users do not use 64-bit Internet Explorer. If the user doesn't even know where the executable is located, you can assume they are looking for the "standard" 32-bit browser. My answer spells out the location of the 32-bit browser on either platform, since the OP did not specify which he is on. If you really care that much, downvote me.

Comment: @MDMarra I won't downvote you because you are good for community :) but have to downvote this answer because it's kind of misleading and people use answers for reference even if they are old. The default IE on x64 is indeed 64-bit not 32-bit.

Comment: @orad As of IE 9 on Windows 7, it was not possible to make IE default to 64-bit (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_7/i-have-windows-7-64-bit-and-need-to-use-internet/babaa5f8-ff06-4ea2-aef6-a9416d65f981) - you had to explicitly run the 64-bit version if you wanted it.  I see on a machine that I'm using now with IE 11 on Windows 8 that 64-bit IE is now the default.  So the switch-over must have happened somewhere in-between.

Answer (score 13):

> Important: Windows 7 no longer supports
>   the ability to modify the registry to
>   get the special Internet Explorer icon
>   to appear on your desktop. This change
>   was made to ensure Internet Explorer
>   could be removed easily for compliance
>   reasons.

OK, let's forget about this official business for a moment :)

If you want the **special Internet Explorer icon** back, copy the following code into [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-100000000001}]
@="Internet Explorer"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-100000000001}]
@="Internet Explorer"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-100000000001}\\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\ieframe.dll,-190"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-100000000001}\\shell]
@=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-100000000001}\\shell\NoAddOns]
@="No add-ons(&N)"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-100000000001}\\shell\NoAddOns\Command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe\" -extoff"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-100000000001}\\shell\Open]
@="Open home page(&H)"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-100000000001}\\shell\Open\Command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-100000000001}\\shell\Set]
@="Properties(&R)"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-100000000001}\\shell\Set\Command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\rundll32.exe\" C:\\Windows\\System32\\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL C:\\Windows\\System32\\inetcpl.cpl"
```

Save it as a REG file, i.e. IEicon.reg. Import this file into the registry and press <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh your desktop.

Voilá, there's your special Internet Explorer icon in all its beauty :)

[image]

No ugly shortcut arrow, and the usual options of the special icon (**Properties** will open Internet Options) ... oh, and it is perfectly safe from accidental deletion. :)

If you want to remove this icon, delete the following registry key:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-100000000001}`

Comment: @Molly If I ever get my answers downvoted w/o a comment, I assume they just didn't like my tone.

Comment: @Chris Dwyer - well, i assume they have no good reason and if they do, they're lacking the guts to let the readers know why they think it's a poor answer, bad style either way.

Comment: Deleting the registry key removed the icon, but there is still some blank, white "placeholder" icon that keeps showing up I can delete it, but it just comes back after refreshing the desktop. Any idea how I can get rid of that?

Answer (score 2):

Click `Start > Run` and type `iexplore`. Then open `Task manager` and switch to `Processes` tab, right click and select `Properties`.